# My pencil keeps breaking or my pencil lead keeps breaking?

Tags: collocations

My pencil keeps breaking / my pencil lead keeps breaking? Which one of these two is very common among native speaker of English language?

Comment: How can we say which is very common? This would require many years of research.

Comment: A pencil once broken is not much use, so I understand you to refer to the less disastrous breaking of the lead only - which may happens several times but may be easily repaired. Your first version therefore implies the latter. The second version is correct and precise in meaning. Both versions may be used. *very* adds little to the meaning of *common* and could be omitted from your question.

Comment: For wooden pencils there’s not much difference- one is a little more precise.  For mechanical pencils the difference might be more extreme.

Answer (score 2):

Either is correct, but I would find the use of "pencil lead" to be somewhat unusually specific. Saying "my pencil broke" is simpler and will generally be understood to mean that the lead/tip broke. Pencils do not normally break by snapping in half, so there will be a natural assumption that you're talking about the more common failure mode.

Comment: I'd agree. If something more catastrophic happened you might say "my pencil broke in two".